# DevBridge JQuery autocomplete with multiple selections from suggested options

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am working with [DevBridge JQuery autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) and i want the user to be able to pick more than one option for each textbox. 
i.e. If the suggested values of the autocomplete are a,b,c,d the user should be able to pick options a and b in the same textbox.
Is that possible?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I asked the Author of DevBridge autocomplete and he said it was not possible.